# "TMGR is Missing" after repair-installing Windows XP

Tags: windows, boot

I have two OSes installed in my computer.
- Windows XP Professional
- Windows 7 Ultimate (Release Candidate 1/Build 7100)

I used the Windows 7 boot loader by default to choose between OSes.

When I was using my WinXP, my computer gets lagged suddenly and continuously, and the only way to fix it is by repair-installing it (because I've experienced this many times before, but without W7 installed).

Everything goes OK. But when my XP was successfully reinstalled, I cannot boot my Windows 7 anymore.
Every time I tried to boot the harddisk that contains W7, an error appeared. "TMGR is Missing".

Now I have no idea how can I get back to my Windows 7.

Any kind of help would be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

Per this [guide](http://www.ehow.com/how_4836283_repair-mbr-windows.html), boot from the Windows 7 DVD, then select Repair Your Computer and use the command `"bootsect /nt60 C:/"` at the command-prompt.

Comment: Link-only answers are frowned upon. Next time you should copy the steps or something in addition to the link. `;-)`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the BootLoader from Win7 is gone. I haven't used Win7 but, does it have a Recovery Console (from DVD) like XP? If so, you could try to fix the MBR from there (Keyword: fixmbr). At least that would give you Win7 back, but you'll most likely will still have to restore the bootloader yourself.

Comment: In 7, there is no recovery console, instead there is a WinPE (a stripped-down copy of Win7) that provides a GUI dialog with some repair options (though there is a normal Windows command-prompt available—which is much better than the command-prompt of XP's recovery console).

Answer (score -3):

The file `TMGR` is not part of Windows. It is a third-party file used to customize/extend Windows 7's bootmanager functionality, and it can go by different, randomly generated names (for example on another system it may be `QZMGR` or `XNLMGR`).

I have seen two main sources for this sort of file. One is EasyBCD which installs a copy of GRUB if you add certain operating systems to the boot loader. The other is DAZ's Windows 7 Loader which allows an unlicensed copy og Vista/7 to be validated as genuine (so of course it needs to use randomly generated filenames to avoid detection).

In either case, the fix should be the same. Reboot, and press <kbd>F8</kbd> to access the boot options, and select `Repair Your Computer`:

[image]

In the *System Recovery Options* dialog, select `Startup Repair`:

[image]

It should do some scanning and then reinstall the boot sector, record, and loader. Reboot and check if it is fixed. If not, go back and return to the *System Recovery Options* and open a command prompt.

Now type the following commands, (you may want to reboot after each to test if it is fixed yet to avoid using unnecessary steps):

```
bootsect /nt60 SYS

bootrec  /fixmbr

bootrec  /fixboot

bootrec  /rebuildbcd
```

Comment: "TMGR IS MISSING" is the remnant of an error message in the Partition Boot Record of a standard Vista/Win7 install, which has been overwritten by the XP install. There is no "TMGR" file.