# BOOTMGR misssing - no backup image

Tags: windows, boot, bootmgr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [bootmgr is missing on Toshiba laptop with Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/133339/bootmgr-is-missing-on-toshiba-laptop-with-windows-7)

When I try to boot my Acer laptop loaded with Windows 7 Ultimate, it show

> BOOTMGR is missing
>   Press Ctrl + Alt + del to restart.

What can I do to solve this problem? I formatted the drive and tried to re-install. It shows the error since some of the files are missing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [BOOTMGR is missing in my dell inspiron 15(windows7)](http://superuser.com/questions/160055/bootmgr-is-missing-in-my-dell-inspiron-15windows7) and/or ["TMGR is Missing" after repair-installing Windows XP](http://superuser.com/questions/77326/tmgr-is-missing-after-repair-installing-windows-xp) and/or [bootmgr is missing](http://superuser.com/questions/133339/bootmgr-is-missing)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/104341-bootmgr-missing-fix.html) how to fix it. Try it hopefully you will get what you want.

**UPDATE AS Comment says**

1: Insert your bootable media whatever you have like Windows 7 DVD or USB.
2: Boot from the bootable disc or USB.
3: Instead of click on `Install Now` select the option given bellow on dialog box `Repair`.
4: Select the Startup Repair option.

[image]

5: Now click on Startup Repair. Run the startup repair and it will attempt to fix this issue.

**If it doesn't work, follow step 6.**

6: Click on Command Prompt.
A) Type c: and press `Enter`.

`C:\ is the drive letter where Windows 7 is installed. You may replace it with whatever drive letter you want where you have installed Windows 7.`

B) At the C:\ prompt, type cd boot and press `Enter`.

C) At the C:\Boot prompt, type the following commands and press Enter after each command.
`bootrec /RebuildBcd

bootrec /FixMbr

bootrec /FixBoot`

[image]

Now close the command prompt, remove the DVD and reboot your computer.Best of luck.

Comment: @avirk... i made a mistake while trying to fix the problem.. instead of going to repair i did format the C drive.. now i am nowhere...helppppp

Comment: You have any backup image on your external hard drive or on DVD.

Comment: And have you did it just now to fix it or before I suggest you the repair.

Comment: Please avoid Link-only answers, as the link may die in the future.  Consider transcribing your take on the information provided in the link into your answer.

Comment: OK @techie007 I'll but according to me that is good forum I  know for Windows 7 so this would not be there but although I'll update it.

Comment: @avirk Much appreciated if you would.  SU is intended to be a source of answers, not just a dump of links to other sites. :)

Comment: @avrik.. i did it before positing question... i dont have any backup image..i have a windows 7 professional verson with me,,, what actually is the root cause for BOOTMGR missing..?

Comment: @techie007 fixed it for you now I would appreciate to get back your downvote if you like.

Comment: @legendlovermaddy then its much difficult to get back it without formatting and install a fresh copy. And I would suggest you change your question title if you have not backup.

Comment: you might be able to undo the formatting with testdisk - there's a few questions about this on SU

Comment: @avrik.. i formatted the drive and tried re-installing.. it gives error that sme file is missing..

Comment: @legendlovermaddy sme means Some or Same file.

Comment: If it gives the error some files are missing then try another disc. Sometimes disc corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

To repair your BOOTMBR:

1. Put the Windows Vista or Windows 7 installation disc in the disc drive, and then start the computer.
2. Press a key when you are prompted.
3. Select a language, a time, a currency, a keyboard or an input method, and then click Next.
4. Click Repair your computer.
5. Click the operating system that you want to repair, and then click Next.
6. In the System Recovery Options dialog box, click Command Prompt.
7. Type "Bootrec.exe /FixMbr", and then press ENTER.

I've done this several times after having problems with Grub and linux installation.